# ABC: Amalgamated B___? Conglomerates

Tags: single-word-requests

I like to use company ABC ("Amalgamated B___? Conglomerates) as an example acronym/ticker/name for a sprawling multinational corporation.

I can't think of a "B" word that fits. I thought maybe "Bureaucratic" but it's too direct. I'm looking for a word that suggests the standard corporate drivel that is often put out, but isn't so on-the-nose.

Any ideas for a good "B" word that might fit here? Thanks.

Comment: “Business”? Without a definition for the word you’re looking for this seems too broad to me.

Comment: Voting to close because this is clesrly POB, with no clear correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Corporate drivel?

> [*boilerplate*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/boilerplate) - formulaic or hackneyed language.

Or *buzzword*.   But I like boilerplate...

Answer (score 0):

**Buy-in** is an often-used term of jargon in business. It is used generically for obtaining agreement or interest from other people or groups, in addition to having a couple of specific business meanings. [Investopedia explains](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/b/buyin.asp):

> A buy-in in the financial markets is an occurrence in which an investor is forced to repurchase shares of security because the seller of the original shares did not deliver the securities in a timely fashion or did not deliver them at all.

> A buy-in can also be a reference to a person or entity buying shares or a stake in a company or other holding. In psychological terms, the buy-in is the process of someone getting on board with an idea or concept that is not their own but nonetheless appeals to them.

The other meanings could describe a generic acquisitions company. Meanwhile, the "psychological" meaning is one that is quite often used. In a particularly hellish twist of jargon, this form of *buy-in* is a business jargon term adapted from financial jargon.

The term often annoys commentators:

> This means agreement on a course of action, if the most disingenuous kind. Notes David Logan, professor of management and organization at the University of Southern California’s Marshall School of Business: “Asking for someone’s ‘buy-in’ says, ‘I have an idea.  I didn’t involve you because I didn’t value you enough to discuss it with you.  I want you to embrace it as if you were in on it from the beginning, because that would make me feel really good.’” ("The Most Annoying, Pretentious and Useless Business Jargon, [Forbes](https://www.forbes.com/sites/groupthink/2012/01/26/the-most-annoying-pretentious-and-useless-business-jargon/?sh=4bf45642eeaf))

> Buy-in. We have zeeeeeero interest in your actual opinion. What we need here is just the illusion of compliance, by any means possible. The masters of getting buy-in do it in such a way that convinces the buyer-inner that it’s actually THEIR IDEA. ("All The Soul-Sucking Corporate Phrases Everyone Loathes, Interpreted," [LA Mag](https://www.lamag.com/culturefiles/corporate-jargon-interpreted/))

> What does this business buzzword mean and why is it ridiculous? While this word should only be used in Poker, it’s often used in business to determine whether everyone is in agreement on a specific course of action that they themselves had no part in coming up with.
>
> Non-bullshit way of saying what this business buzzword is trying to say. Instead of "Let’s flash this idea to marketing and get buy-in from the rest of the team" try "Let’s see if marketing agrees with our idea." ("The unofficial (slightly sarcastic) thesaurus for business buzzwords." [Honeycopy](https://www.honeycopy.com/copywritingblog/business-buzzwords))

So Amalgamated **Buy-In** Conglomerates is a company that definitely wants you to agree with them. They want your buy-in. For what? Leveraging opportunities.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have made this only a comment, but as comments are closed, I think the answer may be in your question. Rather than "Bureaucratic" why not simply "Bureau of", giving the complete business name of:

- ABC: Amalgamated Bureau of Conglomerates

Admittedly, I wasn't sure from your question whether you wanted the "B word" to be something that "means" corporate drivel (when I like the suggestion *buzzword* which came from @stevesliva), or simply to be an example of such drivel, when "Bureau of" seems to work, and gives a nicely "Doesn't actually mean anything" name for the business.

I was also attracted to the typical business cliché "Blue-Sky Thinking", but wasn't sure how to make that work.